# retornar variables true y false en ASP.NET Core LinQ

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, linq

estoy tratando de que al ingresar un numero y es igual al que tengo en mi bd , me regrese mi variables vendedor , reparto y preventista true y el númer que ingrese , en caso contrario , si el número que ingreso es diferente al de bd , me regrese vendedor , reparto y preventista false.
intenté esto , pero me devuelve esto en mi postman ¿que error hay?.Gracias por su ayuda

**este es el código**

```
[HttpGet("imeiypin/{IMEI}/{PIN}")]
        public ActionResult ugv_confirmaPIN(string imei , string pin)
        {
            Boolean vendedor;
            Boolean reparto;
            Boolean preventista;
            string data;
            var usuario = from codusuario in _context.AfcmaPersonas select codusuario.CodUsuario;
            if(imei.Equals(usuario))
            {
                vendedor = true;
                reparto = true;
                preventista = true;
                data = ("true" + "," + vendedor.ToString()+ ","+reparto.ToString()+ "," + usuario.ToString()+ "," + preventista);
            }
            else
            {
                vendedor = false;
                reparto = false;
                preventista = false;
                data = ("true" + "," + vendedor.ToString() + "," + reparto.ToString() + "," + usuario.ToString() + "," + preventista);
            }
            return Ok(data);

        }
```

esto me devuelve mi postman
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cuales son las propiedades de codusuario

Comment: que se guarda en AfcmaPersonas